# Ckeditor 5 prevent enter key deleting inline widget

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have a plugin very similar to the one here
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/tutorials/implementing-an-inline-widget.html#demo

I need the user to be able to edit the widget by double clicking, or pressing enter on the highlighted widget.
I have successfully achieved this for the double click, but for enter it just replaces the widget with a carriage return.
I need to prevent the removal of the widget.

```
    this.editor.listenTo( viewDocument, 'keydown', (evt, data) => { 
      console.log(data.keyCode)
      if( data.keyCode === 13 ) {
        evt.stop();  // stop the event and prevent the widget being deleted
    const modelElement = this.editor.editing.mapper.toModelElement(data.target);   
        if( typeof modelElement === "object" ){
          switch (modelElement.name){
            case 'myWidget' :      
              //call external function
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    })
```

i have tried keydown, keyup, keypress and enter events but unfortunately evt.stop()  doesnt seem to stop the widget being replaced with a carriage return.
Is there a way to stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, was missing a return false. The element wasnt in the eventdata. Have to find the selected element instead.

```
this.editor.listenTo( viewDocument, 'enter', (evt, data) => {
   const modelElement = this.editor.model.document.selection.getSelectedElement() || "";
   if( typeof modelElement === "object" ){        
     switch (modelElement.name){
       case 'myWidget' :      
         myFunction(modelElement) 
         evt.stop();  // stop the event and prevent the widget being deleted
         return false;
   }
})
```